# Why aren't Travis build numbers consecutive?

Tags: travis-ci

When using Travis with GitHub, why are some build numbers missing? E.g. at https://travis-ci.org/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/builds, we can see a few missing build numbers between the last successful build (232), and the first build with an error (237).

[image]

How can one find the missing builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travis separates commits that are part of pull requests from commits that are not.

The missing builds are under the [Pull Requests](https://travis-ci.org/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/pull_requests) tab.

[image]